# QGIS timemanager NetCDF raster loads correctly but then run backwards

Tags: qgis, netcdf, timemanager

After timemanager loads correctly my time stamped NetCDF file (stamped in seconds using `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` format), the animation is played backward until it rewinds to the start.

I am using QGIS 3.4 and TimeManager 3.4.

This is not happening for every file. I could not figure out what is responsible of this behavior in my NetCDF file. Removing frame (outside QGIS) in a file that correctly loads can bring this faulty behavior.

Is there any known file format problem that cause this rewinding?

An example of a NetCDF file that does not load properly

```
netcdf knp14sku4_temp-04_2 {
dimensions:
    easting = 1104 ;
    northing = 1104 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (62 currently)
variables:
    double easting(easting) ;
        easting:long_name = "easting UTM WGS84 UTM Zone -36" ;
        easting:standard_name = "easting" ;
        easting:units = "m" ;
    double northing(northing) ;
        northing:long_name = "northing UTM WGS84 UTM Zone -36" ;
        northing:standard_name = "northing" ;
        northing:units = "m" ;
    float temp(time, northing, easting) ;
        temp:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        temp:long_name = "lwir temperature" ;
        temp:standard_name = "lwirTemp" ;
        temp:units = "K" ;
        temp:grid_mapping = "transver_mercator" ;
    int time(time) ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "seconds since 1970-1-1" ;
    char transver_mercator ;
        transver_mercator:spatial_ref = "PROJCS[\"UTM Zone 36, Southern Hemisphere\",GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",33],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",10000000],UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]" ;

// global attributes:
        :Conventions = "CF" ;
        :history = "Mon Jan 27 13:45:59 2020: ncks -d time,351,412 knp14sku4_temp.nc timeSplitFile/knp14sku4_temp-04_2.nc" ;
        :NCO = "4.7.2" ;
data:

 time = 1409060177, 1409060178, 1409060179, 1409060180, 1409060181, 
    1409060182, 1409060183, 1409060184, 1409060185, 1409060186, 1409060187, 
    1409060188, 1409060189, 1409060190, 1409060191, 1409060192, 1409060193, 
    1409060194, 1409060195, 1409060196, 1409060197, 1409060198, 1409060199, 
    1409060200, 1409060201, 1409060202, 1409060203, 1409060204, 1409060205, 
    1409060206, 1409060207, 1409060208, 1409060209, 1409060210, 1409060212, 
    1409060213, 1409060214, 1409060215, 1409060216, 1409060217, 1409060218, 
    1409060219, 1409060220, 1409060221, 1409060222, 1409060223, 1409060224, 
    1409060225, 1409060226, 1409060227, 1409060228, 1409060229, 1409060230, 
    1409060231, 1409060232, 1409060233, 1409060234, 1409060235, 1409060236, 
    1409060237, 1409060242, 1409060243 ;
}
```

Comment: This should probably be a bug report